# How can I equally divide values in two parts while keeping the total equal for pagination for all possible pages?

Tags: php

I am trying to fetch results based on two types of results. First top of search (TOS) and then non top of search (NTOS) so before this by using a single query pagination was easy but since now I am fetching records from two different queries and then showing them together makes it hard. What I want to do is give priority to TOS results over NTOS results and keep total results per page to 39 results. So I would like to make an array dividing the results equally into all possible pages.

I tried to do this but when things become a bit hard I can't get my head around this. So I am looking for answers.

```
$tos = 23;
$ntos = 26;

$loop = true;
$page = 1;
$numPerPage = 39;
$pageData = array();
while ($loop) {
  if ($page == 1) {
    $caltos = (($numPerPage - $tos) > $numPerPage ? ($numPerPage - $tos) : $tos);
    $calntos = (($numPerPage - $caltos) > $ntos ? $ntos : ($numPerPage - $caltos));
  } else {
      foreach ($pageData as $eachPage) {
          $caltos = (($numPerPage - $eachPage['tos']) > ($page * $numPerPage) ? ($numPerPage - $tos) : $tos);
          $calntos = (($numPerPage - $caltos) > $ntos ? $ntos : ($numPerPage - $caltos));      
      }
    $loop = false; 
  }
  $pageData[$page] = array('tos' => $caltos, 'ntos' => $calntos );
  $page++;
}

print_r($pageData);
```

I want to expect the following result by giving it different inputs as:

```
1) TOS: 23 & NTOS: 26
Expected Result: 
[  
  [1] => ['tos' => 23,'tosOffset' => 0, 'ntos' => 16, 'ntosOffset' => 0], 
  [2] => ['ntos' => 10, 'ntosOffset' => 16] 
]

2) TOS: 49 & NTOS: 56
Expected Result:
[  
  [1] => ['tos' => 39, 'tosOffset' => 0], 
  [2] => ['tos' => 10, 'tosOffset' => 39, 'ntos' => 29, 'ntosOffset' => 0],
  [3] => ['ntos' => 27, 'ntosOffset' => 29]
]

3) TOS: 0 & NTOS: 73
Expected Result:
[  
  [1] => ['ntos' => 39, 'ntosOffset' => 0], 
  [2] => ['ntos' => 34, 'ntosOffset' => 39]
]
```

Comment: How do you get this results - from database?

Comment: @u_mulder: I am using symfony doctrine query builder to get the results from the database but at the same time I want to apply `RAND()` as well due to which I can't keep the Top Of Search results on top since `RAND()` messes everything and randomizes all the results. So I divided the results in two queries and on each query I am applying `RAND()` separately, this way I get to render top of search first and the rest after that.

Comment: I supposed you can add flag like `TOP_SEARCH` and sort all results by it.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d791c7a9c0681ceb8d969ad93cb55f07dae49a3b

Comment: @splash58: Thanks for the code sample but it's not working as expected when you input tos as 100 and ntos as 500.

Comment: change tos to ntos in the 2nd array_fill

Comment: @splash58: Great, Thanks.

Comment: @splash58: Can you add offset as well to the results for both tos and ntos for each page so that query will know where to start from? I have update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a work for an usual loop

```
while ($tos or $ntos) {
    $sum = min($tos, $numPerPage);
    if($sum) {
        $pageData[$page]['tos'] = $sum;
    }
    $tos -= $sum;
    $rest = min($ntos, $numPerPage- $sum);
    if($rest) {
        $pageData[$page]['ntos'] = $rest;
    }
    $ntos -= $rest;
    $page++;
}
```

Comment: Please post both code snippets in your answer. I will accept it.